# How to keep `projectile-find-file-hook` from taking a long time in non-project dirs?

Tags: projectile, org-roam

I'm using org-mode and org-roam, with many org files in `~/Documents/org-roam` (and its subdirs). Org sometimes opens lots of those files to find things. Since I have projectile-mode on globally, every file it opens runs `projectile-find-file-hook-function` which takes quite a bit of time (60% of the total time for `org-id-update-id-locations`, for instance).

Those org-roam files aren't in any project; is there an easy way to shortcut `projectile-find-file-hook-function` so it does nothing in certain dirs/subtrees? (I don't want to disable it for all `.org` files, since sometimes my projects have those.)

Comment: I don't know why `projectile-find-file-hook-function` call `org-id-update-id-locations` after a rough glance, but you can modify it to not run if the new open file is not in any project.

Comment: It's the other way around. When I call `org-id-update-id-locations` it opens many files, and each one of them gets `projectile-find-file-hook-function` called on it. Maybe it's time to use defadvice on that function to return early.